# C running same program twice in LINUX

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am wondering if it is possible to run same program twice, and every time it does something different. For instance I have two programs one that writes with fifo pipes and one that reads from it. So there are programA.c and programB.c (simple program, just sending some integers). 
But I would like to run it like that:

```
./program & sleep 1; ./program
```

So one program would have two operation modes.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'd typically write the program so it accepted different parameters.  For example, `./program --mode1 && sleep 1 && ./program --mode2`.  Of course, the `program` could also call `sleep()` itself.

Comment: On what basis would it do something different? It needs something to tell it that it has to behave differently, like a different argument, or different external conditions that it checks. Also note that you can't "run" the C file. It must be compiled.

Comment: my bad about .c
like i said for now i have to programs, and i am trying to join them. I was just wondering what can i do inside the code, so that when i run the second one, some other code will run

Comment: You can have many functions inside `program` and pick them from a pseudorandom number generator. You could check the process list and have a different response for 2nd, 3rd, etc instance of `program`. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I solved the problem with system() function

Comment: By all means, this is possible. Next question.

Comment: Otherwise, it's too unclear to say just anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can run a program however many times you want. However, you may need to ensure that two instances of the same program do not contend for the same resources; for instance, if they both write to the same file, unexpected results may occur.

If you want the same program to do two different things (one writing to the fifo and one reading from it) you will have to ensure that the program can determine which action to take. One way of doing this would be to parse command-line parameters (e.g. invoke one as `myprog --read` and the other as `myprog --write`. Another would be for the program first to check for the existence of the fifo; if it doesn't exist, it could create the fifo and write to it, and if it does exist it could read from it.

Answer (score 1):

Write your program to accept command line arguments like sed or awk. 
Here is a simple example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {

    if( argc == 1 ) printf("You passed in zero arguments and your program is named %s\n", argv[0]);

    if( argc > 1 ){
        int x;
        for(x = 1; x < argc; x++)
            printf("Argument %d is named %s\n",x, argv[x]); //print multiple arguments
    }

return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run this program with no arguments it will tell you that you didn't pass in any arguments; otherwise, you can pass in as many command line arguments as you like and it will print them back out for you.

The point is that this one program does different things depending on the arguments passed into it.